# как записать полученную черех ajax переменную в vue.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, axios

вынес компонент в отдельный файл и хочу получить данные, которые исправно получаются, но вот переменная не перезаписывается. Как изменить state компонента? Переменная выводится в изначальном виде, не меняясь.

```
<template>
    <p> {{ resp }} </p>
</template>
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    let resp = "1";
    axios.get('http://localhost:1337/api/users')
        .then(function(response) {
            resp = response.data;
        });


    export default {
        name: 'test',
        data () {
            return {
                resp: resp
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В *JavaScript* строки, числа, булевы значения, `null`, `undefined` при присваивании передаются по значению.
Когда выполнится `return { resp: resp }` значение `"1"` из глобальной переменной `resp` скопируется в свойство `resp` возвращаемого объекта.
Это означает, что при изменении глобальной переменной `resp`, свойство `resp` компонента не изменится.

---

Минимальный код, иллюстрирующий вашу проблему:

```js
let resp = "1";

// имитируем обращение к api, 
// основная задача сохранить асинхронное изменение переменной `resp`
setTimeout(() => { resp = 2 }, 0);

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      resp: resp
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <p> {{ resp }} </p>
</div>
```

---

Чтобы решить проблему, можно передавать значение `resp` в объекте

```js
let resp = { value: "1" };

setTimeout(() => { resp.value = 2 }, 0);

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data () {
    return {
      resp: resp
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <p> {{ resp.value }} </p>
</div>
```

Можно использовать [хуки жизненного цикла](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%E2%80%94-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0)

```js
let resp = "1";

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data () {
    return {
      resp: resp
    }
  },
  created () {
   setTimeout(() => { this.resp = 2 }, 0); // изменяем значение уже не глобальной переменной `resp`, а свойство `resp` компонента
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <p> {{ resp }} </p>
</div>
```